# I want a regex starts with combination of letters and special character and number ex: (37210_M7/4L00) but the Line should end with 0.00 only

Tags: c#, regex

this is My Regexpression but it is not working

```
\b([A-Z0-9]*\/?[a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9A-Z0-9\_]+)\s?(0.00)\b
```

Input :

```
37210M74L00 SWITCH ASSY, LIGHTING & TURN AB 8537 18% 1.000 377.96 377.96 | 0.00

8480M/4L00 NOZZLE, WASHER AA 8708 20% 2.000 32.81 65.62 0.00

P2a2eM74_Loo0 LINING, FRONT FENDER LH AA 8708 28% 1,000 265, G2 265.62 0.00

lksdj lnlkdm lkjdl 59656 adf 65454 df
```

OutPut :

```
37210M74L00 SWITCH ASSY, LIGHTING & TURN AB 8537 18% 1.000 377.96 377.96 | 0.00

8480M/4L00 NOZZLE, WASHER AA 8708 20% 2.000 32.81 65.62 0.00

P2a2eM74_Loo0 LINING, FRONT FENDER LH AA 8708 28% 1,000 265, G2 265.62 0.00
```

Comment: When I have a problem with a regex, I visit this [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: When I have a problem with a regex, I use my private [real world regex tester](http://www.regexformat.com).

Comment: This is the regex you get given the effort of explaining what you're trying to match. `(?m-s)^.*0\.00$` Should you require a more fleshed out regex, take the time and effort to make your question at least partially intelligent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pattern would seem to be correct:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_/]*.*\b0.00$
```

The assumes that the first letter of the first term is alphanumeric only, followed by zero or more alphanumeric, underscore, or forward slash characters.

Note that I place a word boundary `\b` before the terminal `0.00`.  This is to ensure that a number like `30.00` would not accidentally match.

### Demo